# "To be retired" vs. "to be a retiree" vs. "to be a retirant"

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Are both of these responses in current use in modern day AE to the question:

> What's your job?

Is it

> I don't have a job, **I'm retired**.

Or

> I don't have a job, **I'm a retiree**.

Also, does the term of "retirant" have any currency in modern day AE?

> Source: [source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/retirant)>/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not heard retirant used and my spellcheck immediately rejected it.

The other two are good. Retired is an adjective and retiree is a noun. I am retired is the more common in AmE.

Comment: Right. _(Be) retired_ is the intransitive predicate, and _retiree_ is the (rather official and pedantic) intransitive absolutive nominalization. _Retirant_ would draw a blank stare in the US -- though some might guess it referred to the villains in a _Dr. Who_ episode.

Comment: I've never heard the word "retirant" either. It made me think of a dictator that had been kicked out of his country, and is now living in comfortable but boring exile.