# Is someone who retires from their job a retirer or retiree?

Tags: nouns, passive-voice, agent-nouns

Someone told me he was attending a leaving party for "retirees". Being a pedant, I said

> Aren't they retirers, since they are doing the verb [retiring]?

My interlocutor said that since the people in question had no choice about retiring, they were at the mercy of the verb, just as they were at the mercy of the verb "employ" as employees before their retirement.

We could not agree.

Since, in British English, I hear people say

> I've retired

and also

> I'm retired

I am a little bit uncertain. Can a person *be* retired like an obsolete piece of equipment, or is the *retired* in "I am retired" just an adjective as I've assumed?

Are people who retire retirees or retirers?

Comment: Related: [“To be retired” vs. “to be a retiree” vs. “to be a retirant”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156320), [Is the “-ee” suffix changing in meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357748)

Comment: @sumelic thanks, those are really helpful! I'll delete this comment later, but just wanted to mention that I appreciate. Now I've actually learned something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retiree is very common when referring to employees who are soon to retire, who are retiring in the present, or have just done so; retirer is hardly ever seen and many dictionaries do not include it. Retired is just an adjective. A retired person has not been "put on the junk heap". In British employment law, most employees cannot be forced to retire at the mercy of the employer simply because they have reached a certain age, so retirement is generally voluntary. Some British people who have retired call themselves "pensioners".